# How do you survive the first scene?

Tags: gods-will-be-watching

The first scene of this game is a hostage scenario, where you have to watch over four hostages, keep the police away, and manage the ongoing computer hack.  **How do you beat this scenario?**  Do the hostages have any visual 'tells' that indicate their current status?  It is difficult to tell when they are on the verge of making a run for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find the status of the hostages (for eg. Hostage 1 has a *42%* chance to attack), but there are visual 'actions' that can tell you that the hostage *will*  try. Also, please note that this is how I interpreted the hostages actions and may / may not reflect how it is, they may be in different order, or may happen after events leading to it.

---

For starters if they have there legs flat on the floor then it is least plausible for them to try to escape and / or they are calm.

[image: Legs flat on the floor]

---

The second stage is a warning stage, if your hostages are showing this sign, then you should do something about it, whether it is chatting to them or shouting and kicking them, so that they calm down.

[image: warning]

---

Third stage would be them with there legs curled up, I would call this prepared. They are observing, trying to find a split second when you are concentrating on something else. This is when they are most likely to strike, so be prepared!

[image: legs curled up]

---

Anyways, hope this helps you and try to keep those hostages alive. Not like I did..

[image: Not like me.]